# Why do external drives spin up for webpage rendering?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, external-disk

I recently went to some webpage in Chrome and noticed that my external harddrive had to spin up before the page would render.  Does anybody know why OSX does this?

I've noticed it in a few other programs when I get to a file/open dialog, but rendering in Chrome?

Comment: Try disabling the Spotlight for external drives.

Comment: I suspect it is making a font request for a font that is not activated, and it's spinning up the other drives to check the spotlight indices on the external drives to see if the fonts are present there.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I disabled Spotlight indexing on the drive and I haven't seen it again yet.  I'll do a longer test but this looks promising.

Comment: Great, lets see if the rendering needs it or not.

Comment: Ok, it still happens.  My current idea is that the pages that do this either need fonts or uses HTML5 Web Storage.  Will have to test this somehow.

Answer (score 1):

In Activity Monitor.App you can see for each process `Open Files and Ports`. You can do the same things with Instruments.app which is part of the Xcode/Development bundle.

You should dig it that direction, it can be that Chrome loads something for your external Volume.